# Arrays to objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this question and I cannot find the answer:

> Create a function called `firstAndLast` which takes an array and returns an object which has one property. The key of that property should be the first array element and it's value should be the last element in the array. Example:
>   `firstAndLast(["queen", "referee", "cat", "beyonce"])` should return `{queen: "beyonce"}`.

Comment: This sounds like homework

Comment: What's *your* question?

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes indeed it is a homework. I've been learning JS for the past 4 weeks only. and this is very helpful, I promise I will add the rest soon. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some diversity of approaches (admittedly esoteric, but fun!):

```
function firstAndLast(a, o){
    return !(o = {}, o[a.shift()] = a.pop()) || o;
}

console.log(firstAndLast([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(firstAndLast(['a','to','z']));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brtsbLp1/

And, of course:

```
function firstAndLast(a, o){
    return !(o = o || {}, o[a.shift()] = a.pop()) || o;
}

console.log(firstAndLast(['a','to','z']));
console.log(firstAndLast(['a','to','z'], {a:'nother',obj:'ect'}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brtsbLp1/1/

Another fun one:

```
function firstAndLast(a){
    return JSON.parse('{"'+a.shift()+'":"'+a.pop()+'"}');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brtsbLp1/2/

That last one will choke on the first being a number (since labels aren't allowed to be numbers only), plus other issues in general. But this should give some food for thought. The other answers are a bit more obvious.

Comment: This is cool, out of curiosity, would you write things like that ?

Comment: Probably not in practice. I would make it more human-readable for instance. It's probably less expensive to use `.length` that `.pop()` and `.shift()` too.

Comment: Jared, Great job! Keep on and best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the key with `[]`

```
function firstAndLast(arr){
  let o = {};
  o[arr[0]] = arr[arr.length - 1]; // the key is the first elem, the value the last elem of the array
  return o;
}

let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = firstAndLast(a)
```

Comment: This is the real answer, according to the spec.

Comment: Thank you Jared, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstAndLast(arr){
    var obj = {
        }
        var length = arr.length;
        obj[arr [0]]=arr[length-1] //{queen:beyonce}
return obj
}


var arr = ["queen", "referee", "cat", "beyonce"]

var output = firstAndLast(arr) //{queen:beyonce}
```

Comment: Wow!!!! thank you so much!!! Those were some fast answers. I really appreciate all of them. I did not know that I can use (arr). Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyChicaiza - You can only select one as an answer, but you can upvote any answer you like, there's only a limit of one upvote per answer.

Comment: @JimmyChicaiza just saying, this is not exactly as the question you were given is to write a function.

Comment: yes, I see that, I find interesting the responses with not only one way of solving this.